# The use of the word "disjunction" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence

I am not a native English speaker. I have been given the task of reviewing a text written in English. I wonder if I by the following use of the word "disjunction", make myself guilty of the very same crime I accuse my reviewee of, namely that he is using a particular word in a wrong way, simply to portray himself as being eloquent. I claim that "quantitative is used in disjunction to qualitative".

Comment: It is essentially true, in that *disjunction* means 'a lack of correspondence or consistency'. But I think a better illustrative sentence is the one my dictionary gives of *There is a disjunction between the skills taught in education and those demanded in the labour market*. Don't be afraid to use a dictionary yourself!

Comment: I am not comparing the two words though. I commented on a particular usage of the word quantitative, and wanted to let the respondent know that quantitative is most often used as meaning the opposite of qualitative when collecting data. Not, as he thought, that a $200 car is "quantiatively cheap".
I argued that he used the word to "appear eloquent", but now I regret my wordings since I fear I myself used "disjunction" to appear eloquent. Which I did :(

Comment: You are right to point out that *quantitatively cheaper* could be more easily said as, "less expensive"  but I think if you had written your comment on my paper I would have been stumped as to what you meant.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're saying, He's incorrect, you're unidiomatic.

Comment: @Jim, just so that I get it (im tired, it is late in my part of the world), how can something be cheap in any other way? At best, it seems to me it is a tautology.
To my understanding, quantitative is an adjective used only about objects that could also potentially be qualitative. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Something can be called cheap if it is of low quality:  "This thing is so cheap it broke the first time I tried to use it."   Your writer wants to use the word cheap, but want it interpreted as inexpensive not of low quality, so he adds *quantitatively*.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, I had the feeling that I was being unidiomatic.

Comment: Good point @Jim! Love this place :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply looking for

> contrast

or indeed

> opposite

"quantitative is used in contrast to qualitative"

"quantitative is the opposite of qualitative"

As you say, "wanted to let the respondent know that quantitative is most often used as meaning the opposite of qualitative when collecting data".

There is no disjunction, whatsoever, between "quantitative" and "qualitative". They are just two words.  A disjunction is a "thing" - rather like these "things": "a debate", "tension in the air", "a war", "an ongoing argument".

Please note that your sentence

> "quantitative is most often used as meaning the opposite of qualitative when collecting data"

is perfectly correct and accurately explains that quantitative is most often used as meaning the opposite of qualitative when collecting data.

Comment: Just to keep on pounding my head against this stone wall a little longer, would this sentence be better; "quantitative is used disjunctively to qualitative"?

Comment: Although @JoeBlow, I wasn't "simply looking for contrast or opposite". I was indeed trying very hard myself to use words that I didn't quite comprehend, in order to appear eloquent. A nasty habit, that is sure to come around and bite you.

Comment: Hi Mickey. Answer: n-o, no.